# Bootstrap 5 layout with fixed sidebar - Table pushing content below

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I have a simple layout in Bootstrap 5 with a fixed width left sidebar and a responsive table on the right.

I have set the sidebar to be `d-xl-block` so that at smaller screen sizes it is hidden..

```css
.body { width: auto; }
        
            .side {
                background:green;
                width: 300px !important;
            }
            
            .main {
                background: red;
            }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
    
                <div class="side d-none d-xl-block">
                    Side content
                </div>
        
                <div class="main col">
                    Main content
                    
                    <table class="table table-responsive">

                        <thead>

                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">First</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                                <th scope="col">First</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                                <th scope="col">First</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                                <th scope="col">First</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                                <th scope="col">First</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                                <th scope="col">First</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                            </tr>

                        </thead>
                    
                        <tbody>
                        
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">1</th>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">2</th>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">2</th>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    
                    </table>

                </div>
    
            </div>

        </div>
```

I am experiencing a strange issue, between the sizes of `1200px` and `1368px` the main content drops underneath the sidebar like in the image below..

[image]

I have set the table to be responsive so I was expecting it to scroll horizontally, but instead it seems to be pushing the content below.

Anyone any ideas why this is happening and how to prevent it?

I think it has to be something to do with the right hand col not having a specific width but not sure how to go about resolving it

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot to add `col` class in main div of side column. also, You must need to put your table inside `<div class="table-responsive">` for [responsive table](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/content/tables/#always-responsive).

Your code should be as below.

```css
.body { width: auto; }
.side {
   background:green;
   width: 300px !important;
}
.main {
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
    
                <div class="side d-none d-xl-block col">
                    Side content
                </div>
        
                <div class="main col">
                    Main content
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">

                        <thead>

                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">First</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                                <th scope="col">First</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                                <th scope="col">First</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                                <th scope="col">First</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                                <th scope="col">First</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                                <th scope="col">First</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                            </tr>

                        </thead>
                    
                        <tbody>
                        
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">1</th>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">2</th>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">2</th>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    
                    </table>
</div>

                </div>
    
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Adding col to the sidebar gives it an equal amount of space as the main content, I am wanting it to be 300px wide